# How to compare changes when scraping a website?

Tags: node.js

Follow up to this question: [Trouble monitoring website changes using node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55874600/trouble-monitoring-website-changes-using-node)

I am trying to scrape openmarketcap API and then alert me when the price changes.

So far I've done most of the initial coding, I've used SetInterval to call the function every 2.5 seconds and did see a price change however I'm not getting the results I expected. I am trying to get it to compare to the last call from the old array and compare it to the new scrape. I'm thinking it's a stupid mistake I'm making, still a student of the game!

```
const request = require("request");
const fs = require("fs");

function discord(messages){
    request({
        url: "https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/57143540025348169/notmyrealwebhook",
        method: "POST",
        json: messages
    }),
        function(body, response, error){
            console.log(body);
            if(error){
                console.log(error);
        }
    };
}

const headers = {
    "Accept" : "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3",
    "User-Agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36",
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests" : "1"
}

const options = {
    url: "http://api.openmarketcap.com/api/v1/tokens",
    headers: headers,
    json: true
}

let oldCoinData = [];
let initial = true;

const call = () => {
    request(options, function(err, response, body){

        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }

        const data = body.data;
        let coinData = [];

        if(initial){
            for(i in data){
                oldCoinData.push(data[i])
            }
        }

        if(initial == false){
            for(i in data){
                coinData.push(data[i]);
            }

            oldCoinData = coinData;
        }

        let oldPrice = oldCoinData[0].price_usd;
        let newPrice = coinData[0].price_usd;

        console.log(oldPrice, newPrice);

        if(oldPrice != newPrice){
            console.log("Bitcoin price change!!!!");
            console.log(`Bitcoin was ${oldPrice}, it is now ${newPrice}`);
        }
        else if(oldPrice === newPrice){
            console.log("No changes detected.");
        }

    })
};

initial = false;
const delay = 2500;

setInterval(call, delay);
```

I think my problem lies in oldCoinData = coinData, but I'm unsure how to compare both arrays when it is being reinitialized each time it is being called.

Upon changes, it should have the old array stored and the new scrape should compare the price to the old array. However upon recalling the function it sets them equal due to my line of code oldCoinData = coinData. Unsure how to get it to compare the old and new data. Something is incorrect with my logic because of that.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9IYt.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple things to fix and suggest. For now, let's forget about real openmarketcap api and consider this mocked request funciton

```
let data = [{ price_usd: 5298 }]
setInterval(() => {
  data = [{ price_usd: data[0].price_usd + 100 }]
  console.log('--- price has definitely changed ---')
}, 5000)

const request = (option, cb) => {
  cb(undefined, undefined, { data })
}
```

which just provides every 5 seconds different `price_usd` value, so you can be sure that you are really getting different values.

The first issue is that `initial` is set to false even before `request(...)` callback gets called at least once with `initial` set to true. To fix this, move `initial = false;` to `if(initial){...}`

Next, add a return to the same if statement, because there is no previous data to compare with.

As you suggested, the problem also lies in this assigment `oldCoinData = coinData;`. What you really want to do is overwrite oldCoinData with new data only if the price change is detected, so when price changes again `oldPrice != newPrice` is evaluated to true.

Comment: my man.. thank you so much. I was killing myself trying to figure this out. You helped me understand it way better, I understand my other mistake as it was not returning data to compare to, rookie mistake on my part. However, I have to say I am still a bit confused as to why initial = true goes under the initial = false if condition.